# Rails 3: Handling exceptions from the DB adapter in ActiveRecord models

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here's what I'm trying to do; I thought this to be a common problem, but somehow I couldn't find any related topics...

I have a model with a scoped uniqueness constraint. I've decided to do this by defining a unique index on the table in the migration, like so:

```
class CreateLossRatios < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    ...
    add_index :loss_ratios, [ :tool_id, :ends_at ], :unique => true
  end

  def down
    ...
  end
end
```

This make ActiveRecord throw an exception when trying to save a record violating the index uniqueness. Now I want to make it appear as a validation error. I thought that the best way would be to catch ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique right in the LossRatio model and populate the errors hash with a meaningful message. I've done it like that:

```
class LossRatio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tool

  validates :rate, :ends_at, :tool, :presence => true
  validates_numericality_of :rate
  validates_inclusion_of :rate, :in => (0..1)

  %w{ create save }.each do |name|
    %W{ #{name} #{name}! }.each do |method|
      define_method(method) do |*args|
        begin
          super(*args)
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => ex
          self.errors.add(:ends_at, I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.loss_ratio.attributes.ends_at.not_unique'))
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

This works, but seems a bit cumbersome. I understand that I'm making assumptions here (i.e. what happens if I add another DB level uniqueness constraint etc), but I don't see a way around this. Is there a more elegant solution / best practice when dealing with such scenarios?
One alternative I can think of is using rescue_from, but I don't wanna do this, since

- I don't think this logic belongs in a controller, I want to make it transparent to the application logic
- most likely there will be no associated controller (these objects will be created solely as associations through another model), which makes it even more wrong from my point of view.

Is there a way to make this model rescue from an exception thrown from any instance method? I've tried using a class level rescue clause, but it doesn't catch anything.

---

Another question is whether I should still use AR scoped validation for ends_at. Even with RecordNotUnique handled, the object will still consider itself valid and have its timestamps set after an unsuccessful save attempt. Can it cause any unwanted side effects?

Comment: Besides my comments below, you should not that `save` never raises any exceptions. It just returns true or false.

Comment: Specifically in this case, when validation is done by DB constraints bypassing ActiveRecord, RecordNotUnique is raised by non-bang methods as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should also verify the uniqueness in your model (like gmalette proposed). That way you can fetch most errors before they hit the database. Although it costs you one additional `SELECT` it makes sure you have an actual validation.

With that in place, the database index should only resolve race-conditions when two independent processes try to insert conflicting data at almost the same time. I usually handle these errors by giving an error message asking the user to try again.

It's not really a good idea to selectively handle database errors as this in itself is usually rather error prone. Instead try to handle as much validation as possible in the ruby layer and use the database layer only as a safety net.

Comment: OK this answers my second question (well, most of it) but brings up another one. How would I test the DB-adapter-exception part with the validation in place? The validates_uniqueness_of statement will make the exception go away when saving, so then, should I somehow cause a race condition artificially? How would I do that? Does your last statement mean it's not a good practice to handle DB exceptions like I'm trying to do? Any examples why?

Comment: You can disable all validations by using `model.save(false)`. As to handling it for the user, I figured that these errors are very rare and can have *many* sources at the same time. The solution is always to either try again or to change something and try again. That's up to the user to decide. So then only thing I'd try to handle (if at all) is to create better error messages. But to be honest, I usually have larger usability issues around than improving on these errors :)

Comment: Right, somehow I forgot about the :validate => false option... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To solve the validation problem you can try

`validates_uniqueness_of :ends_at, :scope => :tool_id`

Comment: This won't work when a Tool is being created, since by the time validations are performed, this instance is not saved to the db, so it doesn't have an id and there's no scope to validate against. So this will work only on update actions. I'm actually running into a multitude of different problems here :( I'll post a complete solution as soon as I find one...